# Flutter Windows option not showing

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to run my old project on Windows Debug Mode.(Released couple of days ago).
I updated my flutter version to 2.10 using `flutter upgrade` and I did `flutter doctor` .
Everything is fine but I can't find Windows in my debug option.
Is it because I'm using macOS ?
I just want to test how my app will behave or look on Windows before building the final release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's the problem. You need to be on Windows to build for Windows.
Check [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/desktop), the second note from the top (unless they changed something with the new release).